How to Synchronize Dial Code with Country Selection in Angular Form?
I'm currently building my own country-flag-dropdown component using angular. The goal is to mimic any International Telephone Input like intl-tel-input, etc. This is what I've done so far.
1.country-data.service.ts (the country-data.json is where i've stored the flags locally)
`import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
 import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
 import { Observable } from "rxjs";
 import { ICountry } from "./models/country.interface";

 @Injectable({
    providedIn: "root",
 })
    export class CountryDataService {
    private countryDataUrl = "assets/data/country-data.json"; // Path to JSON file

    public constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    public getCountries(): Observable<ICountry[]> {
        return this.http.get<ICountry[]>(this.countryDataUrl).pipe();
    }
}`


country-data.json (few examples)
[
{
"name": "United States",
"dialCodes": ["+1"],
"image": "src/assets/flags/US.svg",
"emoji": "",
"slug": "US",
"code": "US"
},
{
"name": "Canada",
"dialCodes": ["+1"],
"image": "src/assets/flags/CA.svg",
"emoji": "",
"slug": "CA",
"code": "CA"
},
{
"name": "United Kingdom",
"dialCodes": ["+44"],
"image": "src/assets/flags/GB.svg",
"emoji": "",
"slug": "GB",
"code": "GB"
}
]

country-flag-dropdown-component


`import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { CountryDataService } from "projects/pitxpress-admin-app/src/app/pitxpress/api-services/country/country-data.service";
import { ICountry } from "projects/pitxpress-admin-app/src/app/pitxpress/api-services/country/models/country.interface";
import { PhoneNumberUtil } from "google-libphonenumber";

@Component({
    selector: "app-country-flag-dropdown",
    templateUrl: "./country-flag-dropdown.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./country-flag-dropdown.component.scss"],
})
export class CountryFlagDropdownComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() public form!: FormGroup;
    @Input() public controlName!: string;
    @Output() public phoneNumberChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

    public countries: ICountry[] = [];
    public selectedDialCode: string = "";
    public selectedCountry: ICountry | undefined;
    public countryControl = new FormControl();
    private phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

    public constructor(private countryDataService: CountryDataService) {}

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.countryDataService.getCountries().subscribe((countries) => {
            this.countries = countries;

            // Set initial country to United States if it exists
            const usa = this.countries.find((country) => country.isoCode2 === "US");
            if (usa) {
                this.selectedCountry = usa;
                this.selectedDialCode = usa.dialCodes[0];
                this.countryControl.setValue(this.selectedDialCode, { emitEvent: false });
                this.form.get(this.controlName)?.setValue(this.selectedDialCode);
            }

            // Check if there's an existing phone number
            const phoneNumber = this.form.get(this.controlName)?.value;
            if (phoneNumber) {
                this.selectedDialCode = this.extractDialCode(phoneNumber);
                this.form.get(this.controlName)?.setValue(phoneNumber);
                const iso2Code = this.getIso2CodeFromPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
                if (iso2Code) {
                    this.updateCountrySelectionByIsoCode(iso2Code);
                }
            }
        });

        this.countryControl.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
            this.onCountryChange(value);
        });
    }

    public onCountryChange(dialCode: string): void {
        const selectedCountry = this.countries.find((country) => country.dialCodes.includes(dialCode));
        if (selectedCountry) {
            this.selectedDialCode = dialCode;
            this.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
            const inputValue = this.form.get(this.controlName)?.value.replace(this.selectedDialCode, "");
            this.form.get(this.controlName)?.setValue(this.selectedDialCode + inputValue);
            this.phoneNumberChange.emit(this.selectedDialCode + inputValue);
        } else {
            this.selectedDialCode = "";
            this.selectedCountry = undefined;
            this.form.get(this.controlName)?.setValue("");
            this.phoneNumberChange.emit("");
        }
    }

    public onPhoneNumberInput(event: any): void {
        const inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
        const inputValue = inputElement.value.trim();
        const dialCode = this.extractDialCode(inputValue);
        if (dialCode !== this.selectedDialCode) {
            this.selectedDialCode = dialCode;
        }
        const phoneNumber = inputValue.replace(this.selectedDialCode, "").trim();
        this.form.get(this.controlName)?.setValue(this.selectedDialCode + phoneNumber);
        this.phoneNumberChange.emit(this.selectedDialCode + phoneNumber);

        const iso2Code = this.getIso2CodeFromPhoneNumber(inputElement.value);
        if (iso2Code) {
            this.updateCountrySelectionByIsoCode(iso2Code);
        }
    }

    private extractDialCode(phoneNumber: string): string {
        for (const country of this.countries) {
            if (Array.isArray(country.dialCodes)) {
                for (const dialCode of country.dialCodes) {
                    if (phoneNumber.startsWith(dialCode)) {
                        return dialCode;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    private updateCountrySelectionByIsoCode(isoCode: string): void {
        const selectedCountry = this.countries.find((country) => country.isoCode2 === isoCode);
        if (selectedCountry) {
            this.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
            this.selectedDialCode = selectedCountry.dialCodes[0];
            this.countryControl.setValue(this.selectedDialCode, { emitEvent: false });
            this.form.get(this.controlName)?.setValue(this.selectedDialCode + (this.form.get(this.controlName)?.value.replace(this.selectedDialCode, "").trim() || ""));
        }
    }

    private getIso2CodeFromPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: string): string {
        try {
            const number = this.phoneNumberUtil.parse(phoneNumber, ""); // Use the default region for parsing
            return this.phoneNumberUtil.getRegionCodeForNumber(number) || "";
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error parsing phone number:", error);
            return "";
        }
    }
}`


country-flag-dropdown.html

`<div class="input-group country-dropdown-group" [formGroup]="form">
    <p-dropdown 
        [options]="countries" 
        optionLabel="name" 
        optionValue="dialCodes[0]" 
        [formControl]="countryControl"
        appendTo="body"
        [filter]="true" 
        filterBy="name"
        class="p-inputgroup-addon country-flag-selector">
  
        <ng-template let-country pTemplate="selectedItem">
            <div class="country-selector-item">
                <img [src]="'assets/flags/' + country.slug + '.svg'" class="country-flag" />
                <span>{{ country.slug }}</span>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
  
        <ng-template let-country pTemplate="item">
            <div class="country-selector-item">
                <img [src]="'assets/flags/' + country.slug + '.svg'" class="country-flag" />
                <span>{{ country.name }}</span>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-dropdown>
    <input 
        type="text" 
        pInputText 
        [formControlName]="controlName" 
        maxlength="15" 
        placeholder="Phone Number" 
        class="form-control" 
        (input)="onPhoneNumberInput($event)" />
</div>
`


ICountry interface:

`import { IRegion } from "./region.interface";

/**
 * ICountry is an interface that describes country details.
 */
export interface ICountry {
    /**
     * Country Name.
     */
    name: string;

    /**
     * ISO Code 2.
     */
    isoCode2: string;

    /**
     * ISO Code 3.
     */
    isoCode3: string;

    /**
     * Whether the zip code field is required.
     */
    postCodeRequired: boolean;

    /**
     * The label to used for the zip code.
     */
    postCodeName: string;

    /**
     * Whether the state field is required.
     */
    stateRequired: boolean;

    /**
     * Regions.
     */
    regions: IRegion[];

    /**
     * Dial Code.
     */
    dialCodes: string[];

    /**
     * Images
     */
    image: string;

    /**
     * emoji
     */
    emoji: string;

    /**
     * slug
     */
    slug: string;

    /**
     * code
     */
    code: string;
}
`

My issue is that I'm trying to implement it in a way so that when a user types in a dialCode that flag should be automatically picked up (ex. +91 should set the flag to india automatically), which is what I'm having trouble implementing. I was told The data held in the countries array is invalid - does not match the ICountry format -  why updateCountrySelectionByIsoCode() does not work . Where I am  checking for isoCode2, the data in the array appears to have a property called "slug"? That's why the flag is not changing - it never matches because the properties it is checking do not exist.
I made the necessary changes but still not seeing the intended behavior. I'm using google-libphonenumber to accomplish this. Even in my console I'm able to pick up the iso code but it's not being reflected by changing the flag.
dialCode]
consolelog
